# cell proliferation assays for research proposal

Tags: cell-biology, development, methods, cell-cycle

I'm an undergrad Biology student and I'm working on a research proposal for a certain course. I need help or guide on cell proliferation assays. I have a target gene , recent papers show that this gene's haploinsufficiency increases cell proliferation. However the most recent paper (published in 2020) showed that haploinsufficency decreases cell proliferation instead. I want to investigate this discrepancy but I don't know what methods should I use. In both papers they used immunostaining with Ki67 antibodies and SOX2 and TRB2 markers and in 2020 they also tested cyclin D levels. I'm not an expert at this field and I want to know what methods I can use for my experiment.
Thank You

Comment: There's no discrepancy between those results. Haploinsufficiency means only the gene on one chromosome is producing functional protein, not both chromosomes. Due to this lack of the protein, the cells increase their proliferation. However, in normal cells with both copies of the gene producing functional protein, cell proliferation decreases. That means this protein is a negative regulator of proliferation - if there's not enough of it, proliferation increases; if there's enough of the protein around, proliferation decreases. No discrepancy at all.

Comment: Sorry I didnt write my question right.. I meant that in one paper haploinsufficiency causes increased proliferation and in the other haplo causes decreased prliferation. In the last paper published they said that there is a discrepnacy and it needs to be further investigated

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. Can you please [edit] your question to clarify that?

Comment: It will also help if you can link the specific papers so that one can suggest a good experiment.